# VB.Net issues calling a validation function

Tags: vb.net, validation, if-statement

i have written code to save data to a database, this code works fine. However, when it comes to validating the code, i have been encountering some issues despite the validation code working in console mode. The issue is that when i call the functions (seen below in the code) CheckValidPassword() etc. they dont seem to return the correct value and when it comes to the If statement in the savebutton click event, the code kind of skips it and just saves the data to the database via a datagridview.

Here is the code.

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Dim ValidUserName, ValidPassword, ValidTeacherUsername As Boolean
    Dim Username, Password, TeacherUsername As String
    Username = txtStudentID.Text
    Password = txtStudentPassword.Text
    TeacherUsername = txtTeacherID.Text
    ValidUsernameCheck(ValidUserName, Username)
    ValidPasswordCheck(ValidPassword, Password)
    ValidTeacherUsernameCheck(ValidTeacherUsername, TeacherUsername)
    If ValidUsernameCheck(ValidUserName, Username) <> True Or ValidPasswordCheck(ValidPassword, Password) <> True Or ValidTeacherUsernameCheck(ValidTeacherUsername, TeacherUsername) <> True Then
        MsgBox("Saving failed", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        'Exit Sub
    Else
        Try
            Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DataTable As New DataTable
            Dim DataSet As New DataSet
            Connection.Open() ' the following decleration are used to save content to the table.     
            DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable)
            Dim SQLQuery As String = (<sql>SELECT * FROM Students</sql>)
            dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery, Connection)
            dataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
            Dim newRow As DataRow = DataTable.NewRow
            With newRow ' the with statement allows you do repeatedly apply a property to a certain object
                .Item("StudentID") = txtStudentID.Text ' these statements add the content of the text boxes to these respective fields in the database
                .Item("TeacherID") = txtTeacherID.Text
                .Item("StudentFirstName") = txtStudentFirstname.Text
                .Item("StudentSurname") = txtStudentSurname.Text
                .Item("StudentPassword") = txtStudentPassword.Text
                .Item("StudentGroup") = cbxStudentGroup.Text
            End With
            DataTable.Rows.Add(newRow)
            Dim Command As New OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
            dataAdapter.Update(DataTable) 'updates the table
            Connection.Close()
            ShowItems() ' displays the table
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Connection.Close()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Here are the three functions used to validate the three critical bits of data.

```
Function ValidUsernameCheck(ByRef ValidUserName As Boolean, ByVal Username As String) As Boolean
    Dim Valid1, Valid2 As Boolean
    If Char.IsLetter(Mid(Username, 1, 3)) Then ' takes the first 3 characters of a user name to see if they are 
        ' letters
        Valid1 = True
    Else
        Valid1 = False
    End If

    If Char.IsNumber(Mid(Username, 4, 8)) Then 'does the same with numbers, starting at char(4) and taking 8.
        Valid2 = True
    Else
        Valid2 = False
    End If
    If Valid1 = True And Valid2 = True Then
        ValidUsernameCheck = True
    Else
        ValidUsernameCheck = False
    End If
    Return ValidUsernameCheck
End Function

Function ValidTeacherUsernameCheck(ByRef ValidTeacherUsername As Boolean, ByVal TeacherUsername As String) As Boolean
    Dim Valid1, Valid2 As Boolean
    If Char.IsLetter(Mid(TeacherUsername, 1, 3)) Then ' takes the first 3 characters of a user name to see if they are 
        ' letters
        Valid1 = True
    Else
        Valid1 = False
    End If

    If Char.IsNumber(Mid(TeacherUsername, 4, 8)) Then 'does the same with numbers, starting at char(4) and taking 8.
        Valid2 = True
    Else
        Valid2 = False
    End If
    If Valid1 = True And Valid2 = True Then
        ValidTeacherUsernameCheck = True
    Else
        ValidTeacherUsernameCheck = False
    End If
    Return ValidTeacherUsernameCheck
End Function

Function ValidPasswordCheck(ByRef ValidPassword As Boolean, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Password, "\d").Success Then
        ValidPasswordCheck = True
    Else
        ValidPasswordCheck = False
    End If
    Return ValidPasswordCheck
End Function
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why are you calling validusernamecheck twice? You also pass in a boolean byref, but this doesnt seem to get used at all

Comment: The lines commented `' takes the first 3 characters of a user name to see if they are letters` and similar do not do what you think they do. See the documentation for [Char.IsLetter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - "a Unicode character" means *one* character.

Comment: the proper way to use those functions would be `ValidUserName = ValidUsernameCheck(Username)` then actually do something with the variables.  and of course passwords should never be stored as plaintext.  And you are only closing your connection if an exception happens, but I already showed you the right way to use a connection.

Comment: @Plutonix Yh I'm fine with the connections just need to sort the functions out

Comment: What rule exactly are those function enforcing?  Each name must be 3 letters then some numbers?  You should know that since `ValidUsernameCheck` and `ValidTeacherUsernameCheck` do the exact same thing that you only need one of them since you pass in the string to test.  (you are only fine with the connections until you run out of resources)

Comment: I need them to ensure that the username entered is in the format ABC12345678. I know that they do the same thing. I separated them out for some clarity albeit some may see it as excess code. I will condense it down when I manage to make them work

Comment: @Plutonix Is Andrew Norton correct in saying that the lines commented 'takes the first 3 letters... etc. Doesn't do what I intent it to do?

Comment: @M.Hasan You can confirm it for yourself with `Console.WriteLine(Char.IsLetter(Mid("A12", 1, 3)))` - it outputs `True`. Incidenatlly, if you were using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then it would have pointed out a problem for you which would have led you to find that out.

Comment: you only need something like this for both tests: https://dotnetfiddle.net/foszDv  (or do a for each on the char array)  I dont think the rest of the code will work - the DA is missing the update command

Comment: @Plutonix If you mean the saving part when you say "the rest of the code" I can tell you that it does work I have tested it over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be a bit too complicated. You can return from a function at any point with a `Return` statement - as soon as you detect an input value is incorrect, you can `Return False` because any further validation checks are usually not needed.

It looks like you have at least some familiarity with regexes, so you could use one to check the usernames as well as the password.

The code appears to be setting credentials for a student, so there is no harm in letting the user know which entry had a problem, if any. Also, it is a good idea to tell the user what format the entry should be in.

You are checking the IDs, not the names - you should name the functions appropriately.

So, your code could look like this:

```
Private Function IsIdFormatCorrect(ID As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID) OrElse ID.Length <> 11 Then
        Return False
    End If

    ' require name to be exactly (three letters followed by eight digits)
    Return Regex.IsMatch(ID, "^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{8}$")

End Function

Private Function IsPasswordFormatCorrect(password As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) Then
        Return False
    End If

    ' require password to be only digits and at least four of them
    Return Regex.IsMatch(password, "^[0-9]{4,}$")

End Function

Private Sub bnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnSave.Click
    Dim errorText As String = ""
    If Not IsIdFormatCorrect(txtStudentID.Text) Then
        errorText = "Student ID not in correct format (""ABC12345678"")." & vbCrLf
    End If
    If Not IsIdFormatCorrect(txtTeacherID.Text) Then
        errorText &= "Teacher ID not in correct format (""ABC12345678"")." & vbCrLf
    End If
    If Not IsPasswordFormatCorrect(txtStudentPassword.Text) Then
        errorText &= "Student password not in correct format (at least four digits)."
    End If

    If errorText.Length > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(errorText, "Data entry problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        ' save to database
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks much more efficient than mine.